# Change inline css in nexted div without div id and class name (using css only)

Tags: css

I need to make changes in a Div having inline css.
code below :

```
<div class="videoLayout  hide-for-android">
  <div style="width:695px;height:391px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the inline style in 2nd div to a fixed width...
but only by using css. not javascript.

Can any CSS expert advise on it.
Thanks

Comment: code below :
.
.
.
<div class="videoLayout  hide-for-android">
  <div style="width:695px;height:391px;">
.
.
.
  </div>
</div>

Comment: So you have already done that yea? or you want to override that?

Comment: No i am not able to do it...

Comment: what i want is some way of css to change style="width:695px;height:391px;" to style="width:300px;height:250px;" using CSS

Comment: the div's style i wanna changes has no class or div id. that's why i m not sure how to do it...

Comment: Are you trying to override the inline style?

Answer (score 1):

You can target the inner div using CSS with:

```
.videoLayout > div { width: 695px; }
```

If you need to override the inline style, you can do so with !important:

```
.videoLayout > div { width: 695px !important; }
```

Keep in mind it's best to use that override sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.videoLayout div{
   width:200px;
}
```

What the above does is start off with the `div` you can identify by its class, then get the child `div` within it (the one you want to target). You may want to [read here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Where 200px is the width you want to set. With that in mind you already have this defined in your inline CSS which would indicate you have another error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure of the exact inline style:

```
div[style='width:695px;height:391px;'] {
    width:300px !important;
    height:250px !important;
}
```

Demo Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/66BK9/)